# automatic debugging with gdb

Tags: c++, c, debugging, gdb

I am dealing with a large code base with tons of globals. Under some peculiar set of data it produces the wrong result. I wanted to automatically run few scenarios with gdb in automatic step-by-step execution and periodical dumping 
 of some values and recording the tracing in some file. Doing it manually will ruin my sight and my brain. I speculate that there is some globals mess-up. How to do this automatically? Use some scripting. All this is in RH linux.
Thanks in advance.

tried to do this manually using conditional breaks, but gave up after a while

Comment: It would be probably easier to add logging of variables into the code base you are debugging.

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted to automatically run few scenarios with gdb in automatic step-by-step execution and periodical dumping of some values and recording the tracing in some file.

It may be significantly more effective to run the program under reverse debugger (such as [rr](https://rr-project.org/)), and trace the wrong result back to its source.

> How to do this automatically?

You can't do automatically what you can't express as an algorithm, and you haven't described an algorithm you want to use. If it's something like "stop every 100 times `foo` is called and print the values of these 500 globals", than that's trivially automatable with GDB.

More complicated algorithms are possible with the use of embedded Python.

Comment: Thank you for your response and suggestion, however I don't think that it helps here. To me the reverse debug makes sense when debugging from the point of reaching some conclusion from the "end" is shorter, then from doing that from the "beginning".Also reversed debug means to me that you know where to start the reversed debuggin from, something like a crash. Obviously - not my case because it loolk like ome cumulative effect. What I was asking - interactive gdb script which does: set a conditional break, execute step by step with recording (N times),  report some vars, asks to repeat?. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the `.gdbinit` file in your home folder add

```
add-auto-load-safe-path /path_to_the_folder_containing_your_executable/
```

Now you can create another `.gdbinit` file in the same folder where your executable is that will be loaded when you start gdb from there (the `.gdbinit` file in your home that is also read - useful if you have nice stuff there such as loading pretty printers).

In this `.gdbinit` file, add the code below

```
file your_executable_name
start

# Optional
set args "<any command line parameters you program might need>"

# xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
# Add gdb commands below to set breakpoints, print variable values, etc

# xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

run
```

Gdb is very powerful and I'll list a few things that might help this automation.

- You can set breakpoints with `b filename.ext:line_number` or `b function_name`
- You can use `commands breakpoint_number` (see [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Break-Commands.html#index-breakpoint-commands)) and then list commands that should be run after this breakpoint is hit. Use `end` to finish the commands

  - You know the breakpoint number, since they are created sequencially (note that the `start` will count as a breakpoint and thus the first one you add will be breakpoint 2)
- You can use [convenience variables](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Convenience-Vars.html#index-convenience-variables) to store useful things such as the address of an important object
- The [python api](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Python.html#Python) is very powerful

One idea is that you can save the address of the important global variables (if they are not always accessible) using convenience variables. For instance, add a breakpoint where this global variable is and then add to this breakpoint the command to save the address of this variable to a convenience variable followed by `continue` (with `continue` you will not see gdb stopping there).

```
set $var1 = &myglobal
continue
```

You might want to also delete this breakpoint with `delete breakpoint_number` before `continue` to avoid stopping at this breakpoint again.

Then as long is the object exists you can inspect it using `p $var1` or `p $var1->something` when the program is stopped at a different breakpoint where `myglobal` might not be directly accessible.

In the commands that you add to be run when a breakpoint is hit you can do things such as `echo message explaining where you are`, `p some_var` to see the values of variables or even `python some_complicated_python_code`.

In the case you want to use python for more power it is worth reading the [section about it](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Python.html#Python) in the manual. Let-me give you one example. Suppose one of your global variables was stored in a convenience variable called "$myvar". Then you can pass it to the python interpreter with

```
python myvar = gdb.parse_and_eval("$myvar")
```

You can also pass any variable in the current scope to `parse_and_eval`.
Now, suppose this global variable stores an object of a class with a "n_elem" attribute you want to check. You can print it with

```
python print(myvar["n_elem"])
```

You can also create a python file in the same folder and use

```
python from my_python_file import *
```

to import functions defined there.

With these gdb features you can pretty much automate whatever you might need.